# .htaccess, hide sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to learning how .htaccess works and I am struggling on getting it to work how I want it to.

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteOptions inherit

#ErrorDocument 404 https://tsrvtc.com/_pages/404page.html
#ErrorDocument 500 https://tsrvtc.com/_pages/500page.html
#ErrorDocument 403 https://tsrvtc.com/_pages/403page.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 301 ^/?$ https://www.tsrvtc.com/index

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+_pages/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^_pages/)^(.*)$ /_pages/$1 [L,NC]
#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+vtc_manager/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^vtc_manager/)^(.*)$ /vtc_manager/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tsrvtc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.tsrvtc.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
AuthName "public"
AuthUserFile "/home/tsrvtcco/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
```

It currently works hiding the _pages directory in the url but when I try to hide the vtc_managerm directory then goto the page within that directory it redirects to my domain name and puts index.php at the end. The I am given this error: https://gyazo.com/0cc504188657beafd2042d6332e4bd9b

Here is the layout of the directories:

```
public_html 
  _pages
  vtc_manager
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give example of request url when you access vtc_manager?

Comment: Hi Ben, the URL I am using is www.tsrvtc.com/vtc_manager/index.php. index.php file is within the vtc_manager directory and in the directory public_html the home page is index.html. I even tried to rename the index.html to home.html but it still gave me the error in he gyazo link.

Comment: can you explain what you expect? are you trying to make `/ ` as alias of `/_pages` & `/vtc_manager` at the same time?

Comment: I'm just trying to hide '/_pages' and '/vtc_manager' directory from the URL.

Comment: you are making `/ ` as alias of `/_pages`, and it is not possible to make an alias to another page, in this case `/vtc_manager`. You were making .htaccess that redirect infinitely, due to misconfigured redirect, so it gives internal server error.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, this is all new to me sorry. What would be the best solution to achieve what i am after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error due to misconfigured .htaccess. When you try to dig into it, the apache log shows this error:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>   configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the
>   limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

You were making infinite redirects, by these conditions and rules:

```
1. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
2. RewriteRule (?!^_pages/)^(.*)$ /_pages/$1 [L,NC]

3. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
4. RewriteRule (?!^vtc_manager/)^(.*)$ /vtc_manager/$1 [L,NC]
```

When you made a request `/` and file is not found in the root directory, then the first condition (1.) meets and rule meets. The request uri is rewritten to `/_pages/`. The rewritten request is handled, then handed back to the URL parsing engine again. The second attempt, the first condition (1.) meets, but the rule pattern (2.) does not meet. However, the second condition (3.) meets and rule (4.) meets. The request uri is then rewritten to `/vtc_manager/_pages/`. Then rewritten request is handled and so on.

You should fully read the documentation of [mod_rewrite module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) to understand what you are trying to do.